# What is this rock found in the Illinois Valley of Southern Oregon?

Tags: geology

I found this odd shaped rock along a rocky river bed (dry) near the Illinois river in Cave Junction,  Oregon.  It is shaped like a Club and is super heavy.  It has a distinguishable ring around the base uniform in size,  and makes a dense ringing sound when rubbed?  I see some reflective flakes when turned and grainy but solid material on surface, 18 inches length. any ideas? [image: rock image][image: rock length reference 5 in ruler][image: close up of ring on base]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because.  It is a rock id request, and it should be posted to a board that deals with artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sandspike concretion

[Pictures can be seen here](http://tywkiwdbi.blogspot.com/2013/01/unexplained-sand-spike-concretions.html)

Sometimes, only a spike is found and sometimes the spike has some 'balls' or round concretions attached to it.